# How can i configure apache2 (Linux Mint) to deny any kind of downloading my webpages even via wget?

Tags: linux, web-server, apache-2.4, web-hosting

I need some help regarding apache security configuration on Linux Mint, because i am going to host my webpages so i want to be sure that the apache it's configured in the right way not to allow anybody to downloading the pages or configuration files (to MySQL) via **wget** command.

Apache version is 2.4.18

This is the configuration form the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file

```
<Directory />
Options None
AllowOverride None
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
Options -Indexes
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/config>
Options -Indexes
AllowOverride None
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/blog>
Options -Indexes
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .httpdoverride
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</Files>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
KeepAliveTimeout 5
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAlive On
Timeout 300
```

Notice: I don't have a domain name for now, but i will buy one in the near future. The important thing is that i want to configure and secure the apache server.

Thank you in advance i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: yea... uhh, that's useless to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182553/sites-not-accepting-wget-user-agent-header

Comment: oh, so then how can i protect the sensitive mysql_conf.php file wich is keeping the credentials to the MySQL Database? Can you give me any hint how can i protect this file - basically i need to protect only this file. Because the information is sensitive. Thank you for the fast response

Comment: dont place it in a website root directory. just place it somewhere else that is not accessible from http, and then load it via the absolute file path.

Comment: `mysql_conf.php` is a PHP script file. Once you have set up your web server to process PHP scripts, they cannot be downloaded. Your actual question is a bit misleading, because the essential part to answer the question correctly is the file type you don't want to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

To load a website, it must be downloaded. You can't (practically) do what you are asking.

You could block useragents such as wget in numerous ways (such as with an Apache RewriteCond config), but useragents are supplied by the client; anyone can change the useragent on wget, totally defeating what you intend.